# A user is asking a question, deleting it and reposting it, again and again

Tags: discussion, flags

If you're following [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) questions, you should have noticed this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860258/retrieve-data-with-ng-repeat-in-json-array from the [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5963165/guillaume-nouhaud).

From the last past days, he has been asking several times a question about the same code. Every time he changed one line or two and deleted the old posts. To be honest, such behaviour is really getting on my nerves, because every time he post a the same code, i have to remeber or search what i said on the previous ones, and i'm pretty sure some elements off his new questions was already answered before. I even feel worst than doing the homework of someone, because every time he changes one line, we have a new question. I don't feel like he's even trying since he has started to get answers.

I flagged one of those questions to a moderator, but I think I didn't have enough characters for a proper report, so I'm posting there. What should we do about this? Should be do the same report as for homework questions?

EDIT : just found out that in user's profile posts weren't ordered by date, i found some old posts but not all, so maybe i'm wrong for the delete part....

Comment: First: if someone answers properly, upvote that answer! This will prevent the user from removing the post. Then, flagging seems to be the proper behaviour. Also, I believe the OP may get some kind of warning from the system if he keeps doing this.

Comment: Strange thing is that i was sure there was some upvote already i upvoted the current one we'll see if it stays.

Comment: If you feel that the multiple questions are not useful you can always downvote them as they appear.

Comment: @RobertLongson Already did it, but that doesn't seems efficient.

Comment: Flag for a moderator's attention. A custom mod flag explaining the problem should help.

Comment: They do things like this.  There are many users whose sole interest is getting their answer/s at any cost, irrespective of the impact/s on others.  They will misrepresent, lie, cheat, flag and generally do anything to get a homework answer from others without doing any work themselves..

Comment: Why are we assuming malice? Maybe the person needs to be coached up or perhaps he isn't getting the answer he needs. Maybe we are at fault for not providing the level of support commensurate with the reputation of SO.

Comment: @nicomp, SO has such a good reputation *because* we filter bad questions and do not waste time pandering to the needs of every lazy student on the planet.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Hardly, but I understand your point. I would respond that SO does not operate as a single entity. There are hundreds, probably thousands, of contributors who readily solve homework problems for OPs.

Comment: @nicomp We're answering to his problems : here goes the new one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867921/navigator-not-responding-when-sending-data-in-view-angularjs.

Comment: @nicomp, indeed we do not operate under a hive mind (yet), but the site has a clearly defined goal -- providing the best repository possible for Q/A on programming. Solving homework problems is not part of that goal. Users who do that are arguably misusing the site (and sometimes get downvoted as such).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: A useful problem is a useful problem, and whether that problem comes from homework or not is immaterial. Speaking generally, I don't expect homework problems to be all that interesting, but that's by-the-by and it doesn't mean we should _ever_ downvote simply because something is homework. Downvote because it's not useful, only.

Comment: @nicomp: Could we please restrain ourselves from using phrases like "level of support" when discussing interactions with question-askers? I worry that it really gives the wrong idea of what SO is about.

Comment: @Light, I didn't say that, and we're in agreement here -- alas, *many* homework questions are posted by students of the lazy kind, like the ones mentioned in this meta-question. Those, I believe, are not interesting in the slightest.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi If you're referring to bad, lazy questions, then talk about bad, lazy questions, rather than "homework" questions, because the two aren't the same.  Many bad, lazy questions don't come from homework, and some homework questions aren't bad or lazy.

Comment: *Maybe we are at fault for not providing the level of support* @nicomp - Nearly everyone here is *volunteering* their time.

Comment: @Servy, yeah, you're right, from my context it looked obvious to me but probably not to others. I was indeed referring to bad, lazy questions, some of them being homework.

Comment: For the record: I see no deleted questions by this user at all. I don't see a pattern of them asking something and then deleting it to ask the same thing.

Comment: Looks like this question can be closed then (or at least edited to reflect the actual issue, per Lightness's answer), considering the problem described can't be reproduced, or never existed to begin with.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Flag any question which is a repetition(after a delete) or just a duplication by same user.

If the deletion/re-post was done by the OP as no valid answer was given to the question, then ask the OP to wait till 2 days and set a bounty rather than delete the post. Warn the user of account blockage caused due to re-post & deletion of the same question.

Comment: guess i'll go for that thanks.

Comment: Assuming he has enough rep so add a bounty... if he doesn't understand how SO work, he probably doesn't have a good rep.

Answer (score 52):

Writing a new post for a new question is *right*. If the OP were instead to keep modifying their original question to ask something new, that would be *bad*.

The problem here is actually that the user is just asking too many questions, not spending enough time on their own research and thought before giving up and asking for help. The *very similar code* and *short duration between posts* is a give-away for that. We should give them a polite nudge to slow down a little, if the Stack Exchange software hasn't done so already.

But I see no reason to jump to the conclusion that there's either malice or abuse here.

Comment: too much lazyness is an abuse here form what i understood.

Comment: I redirected him to codereview, this should fit more for him.

Comment: @Walfrat: Code with a problem does _not_ go on Code Review. Please take a step back from this situation. From what I can tell the only one bordering on abuse here is you!

Comment: What he was asking (from the beginning) was more likely a complete rewriting of hiw own unworking code in the end. And well each time he post a new post i forget what i said and the other too, this is just making thing harder for me and i guess i'm not the only one...

Comment: @Walfrat: You can just close the tab and move on to other questions/websites/life

Comment: Of course, but i'm asking on the general way, like "every user should do that" ? I'm pretty sure the answer is no since it's the first time sawing it.

Comment: @Walfrat: No, of course not, but stomping up and down, misrepresenting the facts of the situation and suggesting inappropriate courses of action is not terribly good behaviour either.

Comment: The problem with this strategy is that the user may delete the question while the answer is being written.  There is no joy in having a good answer 90% written, when the question disappears.  Once the user has shown their hand as somebody who deletes their questions, trying to assist them is a fool's errand.

Answer (score 3):

In cases like this, I think that down voting is the best option. It seems that the posts don't show much research, anyway.

If they continue to delete those down voted posts, then they will get a question ban (or "suspension"). They may actually be banned already.

---

Note: The meta effect has gotten way out of hand (-44, *really!?*). There are plenty of poor posts that deserve down votes, so go out and find them. There's no sense in targeting these posts at this point.

Comment: I agree. Although a custom mod flag _may_ be appropriate also, I feel that just by downvoting their questions should make the software catch up with them to stop them asking so many questions (especially as the question _may_ be different enough to justify)

Comment: That is way more down votes than the situation calls for.

Comment: @Suragch Can you clarify what you mean? I wasn't trying to suggest serial down voting, in any case.

Comment: I know you aren't condoning serial downvoting and I think you are right when the vote count is around zero. But I disagree with people downvoting this kind of thing past a certain point. The current count of 44 downvotes is way past too many.

Comment: @Suragch The last time I checked was before I posted the answer, so I had no clue how out of hand it got. But that's what the meta effect does.

Comment: @Suragch *"That is way more down votes than the situation calls for."* The thing about the meta effect is: It raises attention to the post, nothing else. Every vote is the individual statement of a user, regardless of up- or downvote. And... attention was called for, definitely. -44 downvotes (and a delete) is harsh, but that's what happens when you're playing with fire (you'll get burned).