# How should I handle users reposting their closed question with minimal title changes?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, help-vampire

There was this question: [How can I run psexec on the remote PC which isn't in my network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031516/how-can-i-run-psexec-on-the-remote-pc-which-isnt-in-my-network)

In my opinion it was off-topic for two reasons: a) should be on Super User, b) asking for tool recommendations.

It was swiftly closed for reason b).

The OP then created a new question, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69124421/how-can-i-run-psexec-on-the-remote-pc-which-isnt-in-my-network), which was the exact same question and title, but the title was duplicated (so it read `How can I run psexec on the remote PC which isn't in my network? How can I run psexec on the remote PC which isn't in my network?`). I'm assuming this was done to "work around" the closure of the first question.

I saw the duplicated title text and first thought it was a mistake and tried to correct the title, which gave me a duplicate title error. This pointed me towards the original question.

I pointed that out in a comment, after which the OP deleted the old question and edited the title to be exactly the same as it was in the original question. I also voted for closure (which eventually happened, for reason a) this time).

Meanwhile I researched on meta to understand what the right course of action would be, because even before it was deleted, I couldn't select the original quesiton as duplicate target because it didn't have any answers.

I found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345259/1871033), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345208/1871033), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332273/1871033) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321760/1871033), all of which would suggest that the best thing to do would be a custom flag explaining the issue. I did so, with the text `Intentional exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031516, should be deleted`.

However, my flag was declined, with the reason `Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?`.

I went back to see what standard flag I was supposed to use instead, but I couldn't find any that would fit. "Very low quality" maybe, but I think that would have been misleading.

After that I also left a comment about this issue in one of the meta questions, asking for clarification ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345206/what-is-the-proper-way-to-deal-with-help-vampires-that-repost-closed-questions-l#comment866865_345259)), but I didn't get any reply so far, so I'm opening this question now.

Basically I'm asking:

- Is a custom flag the right choice in this situation?
- If yes, was my wording of the flag not clear enough, so the moderator looking at it misunderstood why I flagged the question? What would be the best way to word it next time?
- If not, what would have been the right thing to do instead?

***EDIT (for clarification):** A commenter just pointed out I could have closed as a duplicate because if the duplicate target is by the same user, the "must have an answer" rule doesn't apply. I have to say: I was quite sure I "couldn't" because it didn't have answers, but to be honest I can't remember whether that happened in my mind when I considered it and then I didn't even try because I *thought* it wouldn't work, or whether I actually got an error saying so... So maybe I was wrong and it would have worked if I had tried. I didn't know of the same-user exception, thank you for that. But since it was then deleted, the rest of the question still remains - at the time my flag was handled, the old question was already deleted.*

Comment: First of all, the text was not very informative. Mention that they deleted a question after it was closed and then reposted it, so you can't vote to close as duplicate of the other one. But the question is if that was necessary at all - they reposted a question for which at least two close reasons applied. You could just vote to close (and downvote).

Comment: OK, I see, but wouldn't that just lead to whack-a-mole with the user because ignoring the closure reason when they don't like it would work out fine for them? (Also, the text for declining the flag wasn't very informative either... if it had been "Next time just vote for closure anyway" or something like that, I wouldn't have needed this question now.)

Comment: Eventually the post-ban will put an end to it.

Comment: Got it, so bottom line is: Closing as dup (while the other Q wasn't deleted yet) should have worked because it was the same user, and I just didn't realize that this is the case; and once it _was_ deleted, closing for the OT reason should have sufficed too, because of the post-ban. Thank you.

Comment: Slight correction: To close a question as a duplicate it must be posted by the same user (and the other question not deleted), *or* the other question must have answers where *at least* one has a score > 0. You cannot close a question as a duplicate of another if the other question's answers all have a score of <= 0. (Though, if you are *very* sure thoat one of the answers is a the answer the OP needs, you could upvote the answer first and then vote.)

Comment: I'm not sure on your point, @AlexeiLevenkov , I explicitly say it has to be non-deleted.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Give me a break. [Even David Fullerton writes "dupe" on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux) (granted, not "dup", but still)... [sorry, _Meta Stack Exchange_, not MSE... </salt>] - You see, editing someone's grammar is fine, I do that as well, but `OT` and `dup`(`e`) is standard terminology here, and the (imo slightly condescending) YouTube links wouldn't have been necessary either...

Comment: On a related note, many members, especially newbies, assume that deleting a badly received question is the *right* thing to do. It isn't. Deleted questions are still counted in the question ban algorithm. OTOH, if a question is accumulating a lot of downvotes, deletion does prevent further downvotes. (This doesn't apply to the question linked in the OP because it has no up or down votes). Ideally, the OP of a bad question should improve it, but that's not always possible, eg when the question is totally off-topic.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just close the new one as a duplicate of the old one.

If that's not possible, close the new question with the same reason the old one was closed.

---

Don't use custom flags for something that can be taken care of with the built-in flags. Cases like these don't need a moderator's attention / intervention.

Comment: it is hard to grasp for new users, that they can edit their questions and it gets eventually reopened. so they have no alternatove to post a new questions despite it is similar to the old one. The information provided by the close text

Comment: Of course you're free to add a comment under such a reposted question explaining this, @nbk. I don't agree that they _"have no alternative"_. They clearly do, but they're either not interested in it, or simply unaware.

Comment: newbies don't understand how to handle closed questions, and when they are downvoted, they hope for a new begining. That is why they leave the old one

Comment: That doesn't change the fact the new one should be closed. As I said, you can help'm with a comment if you're so inclined.

Comment: Yea I’m not gonna repeat myself for the 3rd time.

Comment: @nbk is not that asker don't understand, it's that the [close message tells them so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SB8g.png)

Comment: You’ll need to copy the link to the old question. You will not be able to find it by searching in the close dialog. (See my question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333315/6083675)

Comment: @Laurel: Oh that could also have explained my impression that I couldn't close as dup maybe... Thank you

Answer (score 20):

This is treating the symptoms instead of the core issue: [the close dialog recommends people to re-ask their question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SB8g.png). This is a horrible recommendation and a crappy experience for the asker. Until [we fix that message and tell the asker to edit/improve their question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364874/213575), we are going to see more of these cases.

[image]